# Android TV: How To add a password action

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I am trying to build a login screen using the `GuigedStepSupportFragement`. I have a password field and given it `inputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)`, but it doesn't show dots when I am filling in the password.

See here:
[image]

This is my Fragment Code where I add the email and password inputs in the `onCreateActions` method:

```kotlin
class LoginFragment : GuidedStepSupportFragment() {
    private val ACTION_ID_EMAIL = 1.toLong()
    private val ACTION_ID_PASSWORD = ACTION_ID_EMAIL + 1

    override fun onCreateGuidance(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): GuidanceStylist.Guidance {
        return GuidanceStylist.Guidance(
                getString(R.string.setup_login_title),
                getString(R.string.setup_login_description),
                "",
                null
        )
    }

    override fun onCreateActions(actions: MutableList<GuidedAction>, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        actions.add(GuidedAction.Builder(activity)
                .id(ACTION_ID_EMAIL)
                .title(R.string.setup_login_input_email_title)
                .editTitle("")
                .description(R.string.setup_login_input_email_description)
                .inputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS)
                .editInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS)
                .editable(true)
                .build()
        )

        actions.add(GuidedAction.Builder(activity)
                .id(ACTION_ID_PASSWORD)
                .title(R.string.setup_login_input_password_title)
                .editTitle("")
                .description(R.string.setup_login_input_password_description)
                .inputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
                .editInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
                .editable(true)
                .build()
        )
    }

    override fun onCreateButtonActions(actions: MutableList<GuidedAction>,
                                       savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        actions.add(GuidedAction.Builder(activity)
                .clickAction(GuidedAction.ACTION_ID_OK)
                .build()
        )
        actions[actions.size - 1].isEnabled = false
    }

    override fun onGuidedActionEditedAndProceed(action: GuidedAction?): Long {
        if (action?.id == ACTION_ID_EMAIL) {
            // todo validate

            action.description = action.editTitle;

            return GuidedAction.ACTION_ID_NEXT;
        }

        if (action?.id == ACTION_ID_PASSWORD) {
            action.description = action.editTitle;

            return GuidedAction.ACTION_ID_NEXT;
        }


        return super.onGuidedActionEditedAndProceed(action)
    }
}
```

How do I make the password input behave like a password field?

Answer (score 1):

Below works

```
GuidedAction.Builder(activity)
            .id(PASSWORD.toLong())
            .title("Password")
            .descriptionEditable(true)
            .descriptionInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
            .descriptionEditInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
            .build()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, it really works! The question is: why Google , why so messy???